# Pipe nohup output to logger w/ different priorities

Tags: nohup, logger

I've got a third-party Python script to run in background using nohup. And instead of piping the output to a file I'd like the output to be appended to the system log using *logger*. Added to that I need the error output to be logged using the priority "user.error" and the regular output "user.notice". This way I'm sure at least the errors pop up in the logs.

Running a simple command w/o nohup seems to work:

```
ls /tmp 1> >(logger --priority user.notice --tag myTag) 2> >(logger --priority user.error --tag myTag)
```

Running this /w nohup however yields unexpected results

```
nohup sh -c ls /tmp 1> >(logger --priority user.notice --tag myTag) 2> >(logger --priority user.error --tag myTag) &
```

The log will contain "nohup: ignoring input" and sometimes even empty entries.

Can somebody help me to write this command properly ?

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the output of `nohup` to logger. To redirect the output of `ls` (or your python script), you can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
nohup sh -c $(ls /tmp 1> >(logger --priority user.notice --tag myTag) 2> >(logger --priority user.error --tag myTag)) &
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works for *Ubuntu. But on Busybox I'm getting the error "-sh: command substitution: line 80: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
-sh: command substitution: line 80: `ls /tmp 1> >(logger --priority user.notice --tag myTag) 2> >(logger --priority user.error --tag myTag))'". Any idea ?